# Trying to use a set list

Tags: java, list, set, hashset

I'm trying to use a Set List in my program for the first time and from everything I've done and researched I seem to be doing this right, but Eclipse is telling me that I can't use List. I do not understand why. Help please!

If you need to know what my program is designed to do, it's supposed to read a selected text file and then display said text without duplicates, punctuation, or capital letters. It works except for this one problem.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Lab7 {

    public interface OrderedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Iterable<T>
    {
        public void add(T element);
        public T removeFront();
        public T removeRear();
        public int size();
        public boolean isEmpty();
        public boolean contains(T element);
        public Iterator<T> iterator();
    }


    public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner scan = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");     
        int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            scan = new Scanner(file);
        }
        else
            return;
        int count = 0;
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            String[] things = {scan.next()};
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(things);

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

            System.out.println(set + scan.next().replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase());
            count++;
        }
        scan.close();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(chooser.getName() + " has " + count + " words.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the wrong type:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

You should:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: Taking a closer look at the code... I'm not sure why you're doing what you're doing here, though.  Why exactly do you make the set?  You don't do anything with it - I take it you're just experimenting with the APIs?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate all duplicate elements in the text file. - Yes I am experimenting with them. I'm still learning all that is Java (:

Edit: When running the code again, the duplicates are not removed. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes.  You are making a couple mistakes;  First off, you are creating a new Set for each iteration of the loop, rather than making one set for the whole loop, and adding to that.  Secondly, you are calling `scan.next()` multiple times in the loop, instead of just once, so you are skipping elements (call scan.next() once, save the reference, and use that!).  Lastly, your print statement is inside the loop, which means it doesn't respect de-duplication!  You need to (1) declare the set, (2) fill the set with a loop, (3) print the set with a second loop.